# How can I extend a generic class

Tags: python, generics

I want to extend a generic class in python and override some of its methods in my base class, my sample below doesn't compile

```py
   class __SyncProductRepo(SyncStore[Product]): ...
```

How can I extend the generic base class SyncStore

I am working with python 3.7 with a venv environment

For more info, here are the snippets

I have a generic class like below

```py
   class AsyncStore(Generic[I]): ...
```

where [I] is a child of an identifiable class

```py
   class Identifiable(Generic[T]): ...
```

and [T] is the return type of identifiable (get_id) method,
In AsyncStore, ensuring that the type I is a child of identifiable, I included this

```py
   I = TypeVar('I', bound=Identifiable[Any])
```

Here is how I intended to consume that code
Product.py is as follows

```py
   class Product(BaseModel, Identifiable[str]):

    def get_id(self) -> str:
        return self._id
   ...
```

__SyncproductRepo.py is as follows

```py
   class __SyncProductRepo(SyncStore[Product]): ...
```

My expectation is that this should compile and execute

```py
   class __SyncProductRepo(SyncStore[Product]): ...
```

This doesnt compile and fails with

```sh
   TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module 'src.models.Product' ...
```

Comment: Chances are, that your import in `__SyncproductRepo.py` is wrong. The error message indicates that the name `Product` is assigned to the _module_ Product.py, not the _class_ `Product` defined inside it. Unfortunately, the code snippets you share don't allow for more than guesswork. It probably boils down to changing sth. along the lines of `from src.models import Product` to `from src.models.Product import Product`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @shmee answer, I found out where the problem is. I was importing the wrong product instead of Product. Thanks